# Unable to find the row no causing an error in product csv

Tags: magento-1.8, import, mysql

While importing product csv file in magento 1.8.1 I am getting below error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null

I want to find out the row causing the error.

Comment: are you getting this error after some products import or else this err u getting the moment import is strated ?

Comment: I am getting this after the product import complete.

Comment: I have experienced this error when I forgot to have 'media_attribute_id' in my CSV file and tried to import media images. Check if you have the same problem.

Comment: media_attribute_id is placed well, but the think is I want to know the csv row number that creating the issue. I am trying to upload more than 5K products at a time.